# sql query to find out consecutive occurance of same character

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to have an Oracle SQL query which will find out the rows where specific field value has consecutive character occurrence more than 2 times

```
Field1
---------------
asdfgh
asdewr
aaasdf
sssrty
sswasv
vvvruy8
<<this keeps going>>
```

from above, need to select only below:

```
aaasdf
sssrty
vvvruy8
```

Comment: Does the repeated sequence have to be the first few characters, or is this just some sample data? In other words, if you had the string `'abcxxx'`, should it also be returned?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. the occurance can ve anywhere. 'abcxxx' will also be returned.

Comment: What version of RDBMS you are using? Can those repeated characters appear anywhere in a string or just at the beginning?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov i am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov repeated characters can appear anywhere within the string

Comment: Then the easiest way to get it done is to use `regexp_like()` regular expression function. [Take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26911596/997660) at the @Aramillo 's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try usin `regexp_like` like this:

```
select  field from 
(select 'asdaaa' field from dual 
 union all select 'asdxx' from dual 
 union all select 'asdxxx' from dual 
 union all select 'asd1111' from dual) 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(field, '(.+?)\1{2,}?')
```

This returns strings with consecutive character with 3 or more ocurrences:

```
FIELD  
-------
asdaaa 
asdxxx 
asd1111

3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Query by letters like this:

```
SELECT fieldname
FROM tablename
WHERE SUBSTR(fieldname, 1, 1) = SUBSTR(fieldname, 2, 1)
AND   SUBSTR(fieldname, 1, 1) = SUBSTR(fieldname, 3, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @jherran .. but occurance of consecutive characters can be anywhere in the string ..